# Recursive Function in Python redundantly checking folders

Tags: python, recursion, path, directory, os.walk

I am writing a recursive function to search through a short directory structure. What's happening is that it checks each folder correctly, but then it opens each folder AGAIN! I'm not sure why it does this. Any suggestions?  (note: Originally, the "for dir in dirs" loop was at the bottom, but I thought it may help to move it. Obviously it did not)

```
def Parse_Directory_Tree(path,filetype,a,b):
    for(path,dirs,files) in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            print("next dir:",path+dir)
            Parse_Directory_Tree((path + dir +'/'),filetype,a,b)

        if(len(files) == 1):
            file_nodes_mass = readfile((path+files[0]),filetype)
        else:
            for file in files:
                print("looking at file: ",file)
                if(filetype in file):
                    if(a in file):
                        file_nodes_mass = readfile((path+'/' +file),filetype)
                        continue
                    else:
                        print("not here")
                        continue
                else:
                    continue
```

EDIT:  I have made one change. Before returning to Parse_Directory_Tree, I assigned to path the new path. This has helped but not relieve the problem completely.

Comment: `os.walk` does your recursion for you. You don't need to call it again in the recursion itself.

Comment: You also may want to look into `os.listdir` along with `os.path.isdir` or `os.path.isfile`

Comment: thank you. i got so tied up in doing a recursive function that i forgot why i had chosen os.walk in the first place.

Comment: Posted that as an answer, please accept it if it helped you out so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the actual recursion. `os.walk` recurses through the entire directory tree for you. If you really insist on doing recursion, check out `os.listdir` to list a single directory (non-recursively) together with `os.path.isdir` and `os.path.isfile` to determine what is a folder and what is a file.